# How to bind Direct Mail service on AlibabaCloud with a Domain

Tags: dns, mail-server, alibaba-cloud

I have bought the AlibabaCloud Direct mail service and I would like to map it to my website. 
How I can do that? 
Any help is appreciated Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Enable DirectMail in the Alibaba Console

Step 2. Create DirectMail Domain

Step 3. Create DirectMail DNS Entries

Step 4. Verify DirectMail DNS Entries

Step 5. Create Sender Address

The next steps depend on how your website is configured and what software is running. A typical website uses PHP or node.js. Alibaba has numerous example articles on integrating with different types of website frameworks.

This article is an example of setting up DirectMail with WordPress:

[Using DirectMail for WordPress](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/wordpress-with-lemp-on-alibaba-cloud--part-5-using-directmail-for-wordpress-transactional-email_287645)